# Не работает loop(бесконечный) слайдер swiper

Tags: html, css, scss, slider, swiper

Всем привет! Может кто сможет помочь, почему не работает loop в swiper slider? Ниже код `

```js
const partnersSlider = new Swiper('.partners-slider', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 5.5,
    spaceBetween: 100,
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    }
});
```

```css
.partners {
    &__title {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 48px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 42px;
    }
}

.partners-slider {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    &__wrapper {
        padding: 42px 0 127px 0;
    }
}

button.partners__button-prev {
    left: 29px;
}

button.partners__button-next {
    right: 29px;
}
```

```html
<div class="partners">
    <div class="partners__wrapper">
        <div class="partners__title">НАШИ ПАРТНЁРЫ И КЛИЕНТЫ</div>
            <div class="partners-slider">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/partners/evroopt.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/partners/kommunarka.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/partners/lwo.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/partners/moroz-product.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/partners/shakhter.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/images/partners/friends.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="swiper-button-prev partners__button-prev"></button>
                <button class="swiper-button-next partners__button-next"></button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`